# jQuery Odd Hover Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my current code, http://jsfiddle.net/AW5BK/2/

```
 $(".feedback").hover(function(){
   $(this).animate({marginLeft : "25px"},500);
  },function(){
    $(this).animate({marginLeft : "-25px"},500);
 });
```

It works well, but whenever mousing over and out of the object quickly, it slides open and closes repeatedly. Is there a way to stop that from happening? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for preventing repetitive animation conflict:

```
$(".feedback").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({marginLeft : "25px"},500);
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({marginLeft : "-25px"},500);
});
```

[Here is working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AW5BK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Better use native method:

```
$(".feedback").hover(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).animate({marginLeft : "25px"},500);
},function(){
  e.stopPropagation(e);
  $(this).animate({marginLeft : "-25px"},500);
});
```

Or even better – CSS Transitions:

```
.feedback {
  transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
}

.feedback:hover {
  transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
}
```

Both properties requires prefixes: -webkit-, -moz-, -o- and one without